# Sending mail with dynamic attachment(pdf) using phpmailer returns error in pdf

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmailer

I am attaching and sending an invoice pdf using php mailer.

This is what I am using to send the mail

```
$string = file_get_contents("http://website.com/page/pdf_vouch.php&pvno=$pv&mnth=$mnth&yr=$yr&email=$email&final=$final&name=$ms_n"); 

$mail->AddStringAttachment($string, "sales_invoice.pdf", $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/pdf');
```

By this I am sending some values to a particular page and that will generate the pdf and will send via email with generated pdf as an attachment.

The problem is with the name parameter. When I am giving only the name as a string, the mail with attachment will be sent and the pdf can be opened. But if it is a variable then the mail will sent but the pdf will not open and shows some error like its not decoded properly.

I am fetching the name variable from the database.

Can any one tell me what could be the possible problem.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean the `$name` variable in your `file_get_contents` call - it would help if you gave an example of the value you're using for `$name`. All of those variables are used in the URL, so they will need URL-escaping (for example with `rawurlencode()`) to work reliably. The right way to debug this is to check the return value from your `file_get_contents` call before trying to email the file; then you will only be trying to debug one thing at a time.

Comment: First of all I thank everyone who commented on this question. I solved it. I tried with `rawurlencode()` as you said, but that didn't made any difference in the OP. The space between the name was the problem. I just replaced the spaces with character `+` and it worked fine. Now I can open and view the attachment. Its a shame that I didn't notice the space thing and I was pasting the name from the url to the `file_get_contents`.

Comment: Er, what you did is url-encode the spaces. Sounds like you didn't use rawurlencode correctly. Replacing spaces isn't enough for it to be reliable. You should url-encode all the vars, not just the name, as I originally suggested.

Comment: But if the name variable itself was making the problem, url-encoding the name variable should work right? I did like this,

`$string = file_get_contents("http://website.com/page/pdf_vouch.php&pvno=$pv&mnth=$mnth&yr=$yr&email=$email&final=$final&name=urlencode($ms_n)")`;

Comment: No, functions inside strings are not evaluated. Do it like this: `file_get_contents("http://website.com/page/pdf_vouch.php&pvno=$pv&mnth=$mnth&yr=‌​$yr&email=$email&final=$final&name=".urlencode($ms_n));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to URL-encode any parameters embedded in a URL:

```
$string = file_get_contents(
    "http://website.com/page/pdf_vouch.php&pvno=".rawurlencode($pv).
    "&mnth=".rawurlencode($mnth).
    "&yr‌​=‌".rawurlencode(​$yr).
    "&email=".rawurlencode($email).
    "&final=".rawurlencode($final).
    "&name=".rawurlencode($ms_n)
);
```

`urlencode()` produces Javascript-style encoding, using `+` to encode spaces, which is slightly more readable where URLs are shown to users, but that's not a concern when it's all happening on the back-end, as in this case. For a more robust encoding, use `rawurlencode()`, which encodes spaces as `%20`.

Correct encoding is especially important when your variables may contain characters that are meaningful in URLs, which is the problem I suspect you were having - for example if `$final` contained `&name=foo`, it would result in confusion with the real `name` parameter if it is not encoded.

You may be able to skip some of these if you have already validated them (e.g. if you already know that `$yr` only contains digits).

This question would have been much quicker to answer if you had provided example values of the variables you were embedding in the URL.

Answer (score -1):

As PHPMailer would not auto-fetch the remote content, you need to do it yourself.

So you go:

```
// we can use file_get_contents to fetch binary data from a remote location
$url = 'http://website.com/page/pdf_vouch.php&pvno=$pv&mnth=$mnth&yr=$yr&email=$email&final=$final&name=$ms_n';
$binary_content = file_get_contents($url);

// You should perform a check to see if the content
// was actually fetched. Use the === (strict) operator to
// check $binary_content for false.
if ($binary_content) {
   throw new Exception("Could not fetch remote content from: '$url'");
}

// $mail must have been created
$mail->AddStringAttachment($binary_content, "sales_invoice.pdf", $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/pdf');

// continue building your mail object...
```

Comment: This is just wrong. The URL does not return the name of a file, but the content, so `addStringAttachment` is correct. Adding quotes to the URL params makes no difference at all.

Comment: How can you be so sure of the quotes? Since OP doesn't have problems when he just types the name parameter, quotes could save him.

Comment: To be fair, the OP didn't give an example of a name value, so we can't be sure, but it would be extremely unusual to quote URL params like that, and it makes no difference if the variables need URL-encoding anyway.

Comment: Why put in the comment about checking for strict equality, but then not do it?

Comment: Sure, but posting code that can't possibly work isn't a good way to answer the question.

Comment: OK, why don't you post an answer to show OP how to do it then?

Comment: I will when the OP posts sufficient information and responds to my comment on the question. I'm not going to post a wild-guess answer - it's not a  race.

Answer (score -1):

Use `$mail->addAttachment` instead of `$mail->addStringAttachment`.

Comment: Why he shouldn't ? It's not a string he is attaching, it's a file.

Comment: He's not - the URL returns PDF content as a string. It has no filename, it's not stored on disk, it's just a string variable.